# Joomla Component - site model view with different layouts

Tags: joomla, components, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Hello and happy new year :)

I have a question about the development of a component and in this case now for the site. In the backend I have everything ready.

I have a Component->Model->view (formcheck) which contains several layouts:

- default.php
- one.php
- two.php
- finish.php

The basic data from the DB is displayed in the default layout and the user can specify additional data. At the end there are two buttons (one and two), which call the corresponding layout (one, two). In these two layouts the user can enter further data, which are then processed. With the button "finish" the last layout is called. In the finish layout, the data is finally processed and only stored here in the DB.

The data will be stored in the session until the end and only after processing in the last layout will it be stored in the DB.

The user can only go one way at a time default -> one -> finish or default -> two -> finish.

Currently I have the logic (get session-data, process, save session) in the layouts. But I wanted to outsource this better, because layout and logic are separated. But where do I put the logic and how do I call the layouts?

In my thick joomla book there is unfortunately no such thing. :(

---

P.S. The forms in the views are without form.xml, because the layouts are structured differently.

Comment: You have a Joomla Stack Exchange account.  Please post your Joomla questions there.